# How to debug a get request in php using curl

Tags: php, rest, debugging, curl, get

I'm trying to make a get request in php using curl.   This is what I'm doing:

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "username:password");

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$result = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

printf($result);
```

But $result doesn't print out anything, no success or failure message.   I've successfully reached the endpoint via postman and in a web browser so I know it works.   Printing out $curl prints: "Resource #1" which makes me think curl is properly installed on the server.

I'm not sure what steps to take next to make things work.

Comment: If you want to debug it then start with var_dump or var_export not printf. That at least will give you type as well as value so you know eg if you got a boolean back.

Comment: `curl_error()`. And make sure to turn on errors, `error_reporting(E_ALL);`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add a few more option for troubleshooting purposes.

Check for an error response.

If no error, get the details:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR,true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING,"");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);

$data = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)){
    $data .= 'Retreive Base Page Error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}
else {
  $skip = intval(curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE)); 
  $head = substr($data,0,$skip);
  $data = substr($data,$skip);
  $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
  $info = var_export($info,true);
}
echo $head;
echo $info;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize curl's CURLOPT_VERBOSE and CURLOPT_STDERR like this:

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "username:password");

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$verbose = fopen('php://temp', 'w+');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_STDERR, $verbose);


$result = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

rewind($verbose);
$verboseLog = stream_get_contents($verbose);
echo "Verbose information:\n<pre>", htmlspecialchars($verboseLog), "</pre>\n";



printf($result);
```