# How to debug curl in PHP?

Tags: php, curl

I want to test whether everything is okay or not with the curl in my PHP installation,

I tried the below code, but it I got internal server error! Would anybody help me with this.

```
   <?php
// Create a cURL handle
$ch = curl_init('http://xx.xx.xx.xxx/Dinga/');

// Execute
curl_exec($ch);

// Check if any error occurred
if (!curl_errno($ch)) {
  $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
  echo 'Took ', $info['total_time'], ' seconds to send a request to ', $info['url'], "\n";
}

// Close handle
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Comment: Code is working fine,please check the URL you are passing. try to hit same URL via browser and check the response

Comment: Get all status by `print_r( $info);`

Comment: Check this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30181758/3261332).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following code in the start and try again.

```
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);    
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

And if there is any parsing issue, then you will have to edit php.ini file and set this param

```
display_errors = on
```

Answer (score 2):

try this  use this into before curl close

```
if(curl_error($ch))
{
echo 'curl error is -' . curl_error($ch);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Locally I did this

```
$fp = fopen('/tmp/errorlog.txt', 'w');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, $fp);
```